# B&W TV show where people in a space ship are eaten by a plant

Tags: story-identification, tv

I don't know if I dreamt this story or of it was real but I remember watching this old black and white sci fi TV show. A group of people are taking a trip in a luxurious space ship. Something strange starts happening to the crew and passengers.

Some stuff happens that I don't remember but in the end we find out that there was a plant in the ship that mutated from "space radiation" or something like that and grew huge and hungry for humans.

The show was something akin to Twilight Zone or X Minus One. Does this ring a bell to anyone or did I just dream it?

Comment: This is almost certainly not it, but I'm vaguely reminded of the old *Doctor Who* episode ["Nightmare of Eden"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightmare_of_Eden). It wasn't black-and-white (and being from 1979, it probably wasn't broadcast that way in many places), but it had the luxury liner and the weird plants, although the people-killing monsters were actually made of drugs (it was the 70s). Also from *Who*: ["Terror of the Vervoids"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terror_of_the_Vervoids); genetically engineered plant-monsters on board a luxury space cruise start killing people

Comment: Nope not a Dr Who.  Was much more like Twilight Zone, think it was short with a twist at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be an episode of [*The Outer Limits*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Outer_Limits_(1963_TV_series)), ["Counterweight"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterweight_(The_Outer_Limits)). Wikipedia description (spoilers):

> Four scientists, a newspaper man and a construction tycoon agree to
>   spend 261 days in isolation in an interstellar flight simulation to
>   planet Antheon, a world that would be a potential target for future
>   human colonization. But the experiment is secretly infiltrated by an
>   extraterrestrial presence, who causes the subconscious mind of the
>   various passengers to go amok: one of the passengers finds the doll of
>   his deceased daughter on his bed, while another one is almost choked
>   in his sleep by invisible hands. As months pass onboard, relations
>   between passengers become increasingly tense and uneasy, each one
>   being faced with his own part of darkness. Horror eventually escalates
>   with the plants of one passenger coming to life and destroying one
>   another and the presence incarnating itself into one of the plants and
>   making it grow into a huge, hideous creature. The extraterrestrial
>   mind eventually reveals itself to the entire crew, claiming to be one
>   of Antheon's indigenous inhabitants. The Humans are accused of
>   planning to come to Antheon with intentions of aggressive
>   colonization, one thing the aliens cannot accept. In the end, the
>   simulation is interrupted.

You can also watch it on archive.org:

http://archive.org/details/TheOuterLimits-Tos-2x14-Counterweight

Comment: I remembered the stairs to the stairs to the sleeping area and knew this was the show. Thank you very much.